# How to implement async pattern in windows forms application?

Tags: winforms, mvp, asynchronous

I'm using an MVC pattern in winforms application. I need to call remote service asynchronously. So On some event in View I invoke corresponding Presenter method. In Presenter I call BeginInvoke method of service. But to View must be updated only in Main Thread. I could actualy point CallBack to some function in View, and update it`s controls state, but this conflicts with MVP pattern - View must not be responsible for data it carries. This callback function must be in Presenter. But how then invoke View in Main Thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the callback function in the presenter. Have the presenter call whatever update function on the view is required/have the view observe the presenter's state and handle the 'completed' event. In the view's function, if the view is implemented by a windows Form, test the `InvokeRequired` property to see if the call has come in on the windows thread. If it hasn't, then use `Invoke` to invoke it instead.

```
    private void SetMessage(string message)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SetMessage(message)));
            return;
        }

        button1.Text = message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you assume your form by View? if yes, you can call yourForm.Invoke( put delegate here ); , this will invoke the delegate in main thread. But why do you want to execute it in main thread? why can't you execute in thread of callback?